# Can i export LaTex to a .tex file?

Tags: latex, configuration-files

I'm cofiguring emacs with org. Principally I wrote in emacs using .org file so i want a standard header file where i define al my "use package" file in particular:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[main=british,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mol2chemfig}
```

so here I see that i can create a `header.tex` file containing the upper code, so in the template i can simply recall `#+LaTex_header: \input{path/header.tex}`.
So I want to define it in my `configuration.org` document, and when i star emacs i want that, in addition of inint.el file, i want that it produce also a `header.tex` that i can use.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve does not really require the workaround of generating a header.tex file, though you could certainly do that with Emacs.

The best thing in your case would be to define a custom LaTeX class, so at the beginning of your .org file you would simply call `#+LATEX_CLASS: myarticle`, for example:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
                 '("myarticle"
                   "\\documentclass{scrreprt}
                    \\usepackage{geometry}
                    \\usepackage{fontspec}
                     \\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
                     \\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
                      \\usepackage[main=british,italian]{babel}
                      \\usepackage{chemfig}
                       \\usepackage{mol2chemfig}
 [NO-DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
 [PACKAGES]
 [EXTRA]"
                   ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                   ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                   ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                   ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                   ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Check out [the documentation of ox-latex](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-export.html) for more information.

Comment: i try to implement this but it doesn't work. so i add `(with-eval-after-load 'ox-latex` before and it compile, but when i call the class from a test file it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, ``#+LATEX_CLASS: myarticle``. I just fixed the answer. Good point about ``with-eval-after-load`` as well, but that's a bit tangent to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem easily by configuring the variable `org-packages-alist`, as shown in documentation:

> org-latex-packages-alist is a variable defined in ‘org.el’. Its value
>   is nil
>
> Documentation: Alist of packages to be inserted in every LaTeX header.
>
> These will be inserted after ‘org-latex-default-packages-alist’. Each
>   element is either a cell or a string.
>
> A cell is of the format:
>
> ```
> ("options" "package" SNIPPET-FLAG)
> ```
>
> ....

Take care to insert packages which not conflict with already declared packages in variable `org-latex-default-packages-alist` - this one can be also customized.

This way you do not need any additional export file as header.

Comment: But my aim is to not modify anithing except configuration.org, so everything I need to see is under that file

Answer (score 0):

Thats a different solution but the result is better.
I removes the need for an extra file.
You can add

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{package}
```

To your org-file to do same.
Or if you use *ox-extra*.

```
#+header: header: yes
#+begin_export latex
\usepackage{package}
#+end_export
```

You just need the fix from:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-11/msg00427.html